# merge tags: repository and repositories

Tags: feature-request, tags

These two tags both have roughly the same number of uses (10 and 8, I believe) so we can't just wait for the weaker one to atrophy. Perhaps they should be merged?

Answer (score 5):

I agree that these should be merged. I think I prefer `repositories`, although this is the one with less usage.

I think the important thing in these cases is to check the usage of both tags is fairly similar - and in this case I can't see any difference between the questions tagged [repositories](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/repositories) and those tagged [repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/repository).

Comment: Good point about checking usage